# Translating string to bytes

Tags: haskell

Is there exists some prebuilt fuction in haskell to translate string to bytes?   If not, can you propose me some way to do it in elegant way ?
For example:
`foo "cz" = "\63\7a\00"`

Comment: What do you mean with “to bytes”? A string _is_ already a list of characters which, if they're all ASCII, corresponds to the sequence of bytes in e.g. UTF-8.

Comment: Also, haskell strings are not C-strings - there's no `'\0'` character at the end.

Comment: @rampion: Possibly FFI? As long as OP doesn't [edit] the question to add some details, I think it should get closed as "unclear".

Answer (score 3):

`String` in haskell, is just a synonym for `[Char]`, and `Char` is an instance of `Enum`, so there's `fromEnum :: Char -> Int`, which will transform an individual `Char` into the index of the corresponding unicode codepoint:

```
λ let toUnicodeCodepoints = map fromEnum
λ toUnicodeCodepoints "\0\1\2abc\955λ\9731☃"
[0,1,2,97,98,99,955,955,9731,9731]
```

If you want bytes, then it's a question of encoding. Do you want the bytes from the ASCII encoding of the string? The Latin-1? The UTF-8? The UTF-16 little-endian? (and so on and so forth)

`Data.Text.Encoding` has some facilities for transforming `Text` to various byte encodings:

- encodeUtf16BE
- encodeUtf32BE
- encodeUtf8
- encodeUtf16LE
- encodeUtf32LE

Which, when combined with `Data.Text.pack :: String -> Text` and `Data.ByteString.unpack :: ByteString -> [Word8]` can give you a list of bytes for a given encoding:

```
λ let toUTF8Bytes = Data.ByteString.unpack . encodeUtf8 . Data.Text.pack
λ toUTF8Bytes "\0\1\2abc\955λ\9731☃"
[0,1,2,97,98,99,206,187,206,187,226,152,131,226,152,131]
```

**UPDATE**: Per the comment, if you want to escape all the characters in a string into their hex-escape represenatations, you can use `Numeric.showHex` to get the hex strings:

```
λ let escapeAsHex = showString "\"" . foldr ((showString "\\x" .) . Numeric.showHex . fromEnum) "\""
λ escapeAsHex "\0\1\2abc\955λ\9731☃"
"\"\\x0\\x1\\x2\\x61\\x62\\x63\\x3bb\\x3bb\\x2603\\x2603\""
λ putStrLn $ escapeAsHex "\0\1\2abc\955λ\9731☃"
"\x0\x1\x2\x61\x62\x63\x3bb\x3bb\x2603\x2603"
λ read $ escapeAsHex "\0\1\2abc\955λ\9731☃" :: String
"\NUL\SOH\STXabc\955\955\9731\9731"
```

Comment: I meant convert string (each character) to hex. For example:  `"cc" -> "\63\63"`

Comment: JavaNewbie: See for yourself in ghci, `"c" == "\x63"`. Do you want to print the hex values of each unicode codepoint?